# Sum List of objects using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class:

```
public Class MyClass
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public double quantity {get; set;}
  public double price {get; set;}
  public double value {get; set;}
  public string id1 {get; set;}
  public string id2 {get; set;}
}


List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

The list objects are then populated but the same name can have multiple entries. For example, here is my list overview:

```
[0] "stock A", 200.0, 20.0, 4000, "aa", "bb"
[1] "stock A", 400.0, 20.0, 8000, "aa", "bb"
[2] "stock B", 200.0, 20.0, 4000, "cc", "dd"
[3] "stock A", 200.0, 19, 3800, "aa", "bb"
[4] "stock C", 200.0, 20.0, 4000, "ee", "ff"
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
var groupedStockList = (from t in myList
  group t by new { t.name, t.price }
    into grp
    select new
    {
      grp.Key.name,
      grp.Key.price,

      Quantity = grp.Sum(x => x.quantity)
    }).ToList();
```

The result is that Stock A is grouped but 2 groups for 2 sets of prices, so I have a grouping of 600 stock A with a price of 20 and 200 stocks at a price of 19.

I was thinking I have to go with the average price, i.e. `sum = (quantity * price) / total_quantity` but am lost as how to incorporate this in linq.

Is there anyone who has an approach to this who can help please? I would like to keep ids 1 and 2 also in the list and just sort by name.

Thanks.

EDIT

What I would like to return is this,

```
[0] "stock A", 800, 19.75, 15800, "aa", "bb"
[1] "stock B", 200.0, 20.0, 4000, "cc", "dd"
[2] "stock C", 200.0, 20.0, 4000, "ee", "ff"
```

Comment: Be explicit with what you want returned.  A "list overview"-like listing would be nice...

Comment: ok, i will add it now

Comment: Can you post the code that populates the list?

Comment: The given example has a price of 19.75 for A but the average price is `19.66...`  Is that a typo, or is it really something else?

Comment: @Servy:  It's the weighted average: (4000 + 8000 + 3800)/(200 + 400 + 200).

Comment: @AustinSalonen Then you'll need to adjust the answer, as currently it's not doing that.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var groupedStockList = (from t in myList
    group t by new { t.name, t.id1, t.id2 } into grp
    select new
    {
      Name = grp.Key.name,
      TotalQuantity = grp.Sum(x => x.quantity),
      AvgPrice = grp.Sum(x => x.value) / grp.Sum(x => x.quantity),
      TotalValue = grp.Sum(x => x.value),
      Id1 = grp.Key.id1,
      Id2 = grp.Key.id2     
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this is a modification of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141849/1159478) using method syntax as opposed to query syntax

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => {x.name, x.id1, x.id2})
                   .Select(g => new {
                                         Name = grp.Key.name,
                                         TotalQuantity = grp.Sum(x => x.quantity),
                                         AvgPrice = grp.Average(x => x.price),
                                         TotalValue = grp.Sum(x => x.value),
                                         Id1 = grp.Key.id1,
                                         Id2 = grp.Key.id2     
                                     })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: When you take another answer and use large portions of it to write your own answer, even if you modify it a bit, you need to cite it, otherwise it's plagiarism.

Comment: Noted. I wasn't trying to rip off the other answer just thought it was a valid alternative

Comment: Which is fine to do, you just need to cite the answer.